# select all related objects

Tags: linq

I have a linq query where I'm trying to return all `MlaArticles` that are related to all other `WebObjects` but I'm getting the error: `The specified type member 'RelatedWebObjectIds' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.`

Here's the Model...

```
public abstract class WebObject : IValidatableObject
{
    public WebObject()
    {
        this.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        RelatedTags = new List<Tag>();
        RelatedWebObjects = new List<WebObject>();
    }

    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<WebObject> RelatedWebObjects { get; set; }
    public IList<Guid> RelatedWebObjectIds { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks for your help...

```
List<MlaArticle> assignedWebObjects = (from e in db.MlaArticles
                                       where
                                           (from w in db.WebObjects
                                            from r in w.RelatedWebObjectIds
                                            where w.Id == id
                                            select r).Contains(e.Id)
                                       select e).OrderBy(x => x.Title).ToList();
```

New query. Produces different error: `WebObject does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload ... has some invalid arguments.`

```
List<MlaArticle> assignedWebObjects = (from e in db.MlaArticles
                                       where
                                           (from w in db.WebObjects
                                            from r in w.RelatedWebObjects
                                            where w.Id == id
                                            select r.RelatedWebObjectIds).Contains(e.Id)
                                       select e).OrderBy(x => x.Title).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a `RelatedWebObjects` navigation property in your MlaArticle entity? If there is, you can do that instead:

```
List<MlaArticle> assignedWebObjects = (from e in db.MlaArticles
                                       where
                                           (from w in db.WebObjects
                                            from r in w.RelatedWebObjects
                                            where w.Id == id
                                            select r.Id).Contains(e.Id)
                                       select e).OrderBy(x => x.Title).ToList();
```

Comment: yep, there is. but when i reference RelatedWebObjects I get an error for Contains: `WebObject does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload ... has some invalid arguments.`

Comment: Are you sure  you're using the same query? Perhaps you forgot to replace `select r` with `select r.Id`?

Comment: it would need to be r.RelatedWebObjectIds but that still throws the same error. I'll put my new query above...

Comment: well, using r.RelatedWebObjectIds or r.Id doesn't have the same meaning... but I don't know your model, so it's difficult to tell which is more correct. You should post your model in the question

Comment: this is the tip of the iceberg. I'll try to sum it up above.

Comment: Thomas, I was wrong, You were right.  It should have been r.Id. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<MlaArticle> assignedWebObjects = (from e in db.MlaArticles
                                       where
                                           (from w in db.WebObjects
                                            from r in w.RelatedWebObjects
                                            where w.Id == id
                                            select r.RelatedWebObjectIds).Any(i => i == e.Id)
                                       select e).OrderBy(x => x.Title).ToList();
```

Comment: `Operator == cannot be applied to operands of type 'IList<System.Guid>' and 'System.Guid'`. e.Id is a Guid and i would be a list of Guids.